# Unable to export basemap from QGIS into NEXTGIS

Tags: qgis, basemap, nextgis

I've exported most of the map including geotiffs from QGIS into NEXTGIS, but I cannot export the basemap.

> error - Import 'Google Satellite' failed. need more than 1 value to
>   unpack.

How do I avoid this error?

Comment: You can't send basemaps to Web GIS unless they are added as TMS services. How was your basemap added? Disclaimer: I'm a developer at NextGIS.

Comment: I actually generated it from QGIS 3 and saved the project as a QGIS 2.18.

Comment: Can you point me to simple documentation that explains how to add a Google satellite basemap to a NEXTGIS web map?

Comment: The simplest way is to use QuickMapServices (QMS) plugin. Open Search QMS window (Web -> QuickMapServices -> Search QMS) and enter your basemap name to search field. In list of found basemaps just click "Add".

Comment: Tried that, and it too seems to fail - different error - Import 'eAtlas EGIP' failed. {"exception": "CalledProcessError", "message": "Unknown exception 'CalledProcessError' in serializer 'raster_layer' attribute 'source'.", "attr": "source", "serializer": "raster_layer"}

Comment: My mistake - the plugin seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As topicstarter reported the problem is solved. The issue occurred while transforming project from QGIS3 to NextGIS QGIS (based on 2.18.x). Re-adding basemap using [QuickMapServices plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/) helped.

**Disclaimer:** I'm developer at NextGIS